# Draw contour line to represent multiple contours

Tags: python, r

I have 5 data sets, each includes multiple scatter points.
If I use the geom_path function in R, I could obtain 5 contours like the following graph shows. 
[image]

Those five contours are annotated outlines from 5 pathologists, what I want to do now is trying to use a single contour to represents these 5. Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: What about averaging them?

Comment: The question is how to do the averaging? Since the numbers of points for each contour are not the same...

Comment: I thought about averaging the interception of each curve with the perpendicular bisectors.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing about the expected behavior of the data I would compute a interpolation over a common parameter space and then average the interpolated values

Comment: Thank you for your help! But to what values do you plan to perform averaging? Along which direction?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by direction, bit the average would depend on the parameterization that you have. Let's suppose that you can use polar coordinates and the angle as parameter then you have $r = r(\theta)$, and you can use that